# Simple polymorphic type annotation in OCaml

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, ocaml

Are some annotations needed to make this typecheck in ocaml ?

```ml
type ('a,'b) roll = Roll of (('b,'a) roll -> 'b)
let unroll (Roll f) = f 

(* nope-   
This definition has type        ('b, 'b) roll -> ('b, 'b) roll -> ('b, 'b) roll
which is less general than  'c. ('b, 'c) roll -> ('b, 'b) roll -> ('b, 'c) roll *)

let rec (-:) : 'c. ('b,'c) roll -> ('a,'b) roll -> ('a, 'c) roll = fun f g ->
  Roll (fun k  ->  unroll f (g -: k)) 


(* nope -- unifies to 1 type ! 
let rec (-:) = fun f g ->
  Roll (fun k  ->  unroll f (g -: k)) 
*)
```

The same code in Haskell requires type annotations

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype Roll a b = Roll (Roll b a  -> b)
unroll (Roll f) = f

(-:) :: forall a b c. Roll b c -> Roll a b -> Roll a c 
(-:)  f g =  Roll (\k  ->  unroll f (g -: k))
```

Comment: `Roll` is a [hyperfunction](https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2021-03-14-hyperfunctions.html): [`Control.Monad.Hyper`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hyperfunctions-0/docs/Control-Monad-Hyper.html)

Comment: @Iceland_jack yep [Coroutining Folds with Hyperfunctions](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5135.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Universally quantifying all the type variables, as in the equivalent Haskell code, seems to work fine:

```ml
let rec (-:) : 'a 'b 'c. ('b, 'c) roll -> ('a, 'b) roll -> ('a, 'c) roll = fun f g ->
  Roll (fun k  ->  unroll f (g -: k))
```

```
val ( -: ) : ('b, 'c) roll -> ('a, 'b) roll -> ('a, 'c) roll = <fun>
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that, but that had some additional type annotation inside ` .. (k: ('c,'a) roll)  ->  unroll ...`  which failed for that reason. (can't we use bound type variables that way inside expressions ?)

Comment: Mixing unification type variables with polymorphic type variables tend to behave badly because they have different scopes. But in your case example, it sounds like it should be fine with at least OCaml ≥ 4.11.1 (where the typing of recursive polymorphic functions have been improved).

Comment: Using locally abstract types (i.e. `type a b c.`) also seems to work fine pre-4.11.1.